# Upload sketch via Bluetooth using HC-06 module

Tags: bluetooth, sketch, uploading, bootloader, hc-06

I'm dealing with an application in which I need to upload sketches remotely to an arduino UNO board. I successufully managed to upload sketches using an HC-06 bluetooth adapter. The only problem is that I am forced to manually press the reset button once the bluetooth link is established. Is there a way to automatically reset the arduino, in a software or hardware way,  so that it will be able to accept and install the incoming and sketch?
Would it be enough to activate a digital pin connected to the reset at the right timing prior the upload process starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a BJT/FET.

For a NPN, connect RST to COLLECTOR, a digital pin in series with a 220 ohm (or whatever’s appropriate) resistor to BASE, and EMITTER to GND.

Just bring the digital pin HIGH to reset your arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a instructable on how to reset the arduino with software

[Instructables link](http://www.instructables.com/id/two-ways-to-reset-arduino-in-software/)